# Inserting data in one table which has two foreign keys (php)

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, foreign-keys

I'm new to this site, and I need some help with my record system. I need to insert the grades of the students into the **grades** table, which has the columns: *gradeid* (PK, auto_increment), *studentid* (FK), *courseid* (FK), *midterm*, *endterm*, *final*, *remark*.

The *studentid* (FK) gets the number from the studentid (PK) of **addrec** table.

The *courseid* (FK) gets the number from the courseid (PK) of **course** table.

Here are the codes that I have experimented (for the umpteenth time) but still got no results:

```
<?php
$host="localhost";  
$username="root"; 
$password=""; 
$db_name="studentrec";


$studentid = $_GET['id'];
$sql1="SELECT studentid FROM addrec WHERE studentid='$studentid'";

if(mysql_query($sql1))
{
$courseid = $_GET['courseid'];
$sql2 = "SELECT courseid FROM course WHERE courseid='$courseid'";

if (mysql_query ($sql2)) 
{
$sql3="INSERT INTO grades(`studentid`, `courseid`, `midterm`, `endterm`, `final`,    remark`) VALUES   ('$studentid','$courseid','$_POST[midterm]','$_POST[endterm]','$_POST[final]','$_POST[remark]' )";
}
if (mysql_query($sql3))
{
    // Success
}
else 
{
    die('Error on query 2: ' . mysql_error($con));
}
}
?>
```

There are no errors whenever I hit the Submit button, but the data I put in the text boxes won't insert into the **grades** table. Help, please? Or suggestions? I'm still studying stuff about PHP. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

youre not connecting to the mySQL : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

also you might notice the big red box on php.net, you should move to PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: Hi. I'm going to check that one. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Query contains error. Try this

```
INSERT INTO grades(studentid,courseid,midterm,endterm,final,remark) VALUES  ('$studentid','$courseid','$_POST[midterm]','$_POST[endterm]','$_POST[final]','$_POST[remark]' );
```

Answer (score 0):

do your db connection first than select db and than

try to replace

```
$sql3="INSERT INTO grades(`studentid`, `courseid`, `midterm`, `endterm`, `final`,    remark`) VALUES   ('$studentid','$courseid','$_POST[midterm]','$_POST[endterm]','$_POST[final]','$_POST[remark]' )";
```

with

```
$sql3="INSERT INTO grades(`studentid`, `courseid`, `midterm`, `endterm`, `final`,    remark`) VALUES('$studentid','$courseid','".$_POST['midterm']."','".$_POST['endterm']."','".$_POST['final']."','".$_POST['remark']."' )";
```

Answer (score 0):

You actual query is like

```
INSERT INTO grades(`studentid`, `courseid`, `midterm`, `endterm`, `final`,remark`) 
VALUES
('$studentid','$courseid','$_POST[midterm]','$_POST[endterm]','$_POST[final]','$_POST[remark]' );
```

You need to put opening **` (tild)** before column remark, so your query will looks like

```
INSERT INTO grades(`studentid`, `courseid`, `midterm`, `endterm`, `final`,`remark`) 
VALUES
('$studentid','$courseid','$_POST[midterm]','$_POST[endterm]','$_POST[final]','$_POST[remark]');
```